# looping though an array with an async method takes only the last element in angular 2 (ecma6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, angular

I have the following code:

```
for( let filename of ["action", "course", "program", "staff", "student"]){
    http.get('data/'+filename+'.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
               staff => localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)
            ));
}
```

transpiled into :

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = ["action", "course", "program", "staff", "student"]; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var filename = _a[_i];
    http.get('data/' + filename + '.json')
        .map(function (res) { return res.json(); })
            .subscribe(function (staff) { return localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)); });
            }
```

Which should loop though an array of stings that has the names of files that has json objects that I wish to load in the local storage.

***Problem goes as follows:***
 I only get the value of the last element stored in the local storage. the rest is gone.

***reason is:***
 
When the time comes to call the `localStorage.setItem` in the `.subscribe()`
The value stored in filename is equal to the last value in the array.

***Ideas I got***

1. Make The HTTP request *synchronous* {sure its a bad idea} but the application actually depend on this data thus I don't mind blocking the ui till its done. | anyhow ng2 documentations shows no clue of how to do that...
2. use Promises which i have no clue how with angular 2
3. find a way to make sure that filename value is some how stored for each loop
4. forget about doing it in a loop and write it down  hard-coded

---

***my code***

*app.ts*

```
import {Component,  bootstrap, NgFor,CORE_DIRECTIVES,OnInit,provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams, RouteData,
    LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy,Location} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({    
    selector: 'app-holder',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]]
})
export class MainComponent {
    constructor(http: Http) {
        if(dataStorage.shouldLoad()){
            for( filename of ["action", "actiontype", "advisertype", "course", "program", "staff", "student"]){
                http.get('data/'+filename+'.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(staff => localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)));
            }
        }
    }
}

bootstrap(MainComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

*index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Star App</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
        });
        System.import('app/app');
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <app-holder>Please wait while Loading...</app-holder>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*backGround checkes:*

- how to use http in ng2 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html
- solving similer issue but with Angular 1 : [how to make synchronous http request in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750814/how-to-make-synchronous-http-request-in-angular-js)
- options that can be set to http calls with ng2 : https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestmode

Comment: can you use [].forEach() (or an equivalent) instead of the loop? (functions have scope, so the filename would be unique to each iteration.)

Comment: Best Answer ! 
Thank you @dandavis

Comment: Personally I think it would be better using forkJoin. Use RxJS :) http://plnkr.co/edit/sl93Fo89NSDn7J8I48y4?p=info

Comment: @EricMartinez Definitely worth checking out. Though The forEach sugestion looks simple enough for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You just fell to the [infamous closure in a loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572).

You'd think ES6 would save you from this with its block scoping? Yes, it does, but only if you actually **declare** your variable:

```
for (let filename of ["action", "course", "program", "staff", "student"]) {
//   ^^^ 
    http.get('data/'+filename+'.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(staff => localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)));
}
```

Comment: I gave that a shot it didn't work.
The issue is still present.

Comment: Ecma 5 I believe ! ---  

 for (var _i = 0, _a = ["action", "actiontype", "advisertype", "course", "program", "staff", "student"]; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
                    var filename = _a[_i];
                    http.get('data/' + filename + '.json').map(function (res) { return res.json(); }).subscribe(function (staff) { return localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)); });
                }

Comment: Readable enough to suggest a bug in your transpiler… What are you using?

Comment: TypeScript , Under WebStorem 11.0.1

Comment: Wow, it looks like [TypeScript intentionally deviates from the ES6 standard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html#let-in-closures) here. I'd suggest pressing on them to support this properly, and until then use ES6 as a compile target and use babel in a second step.

Comment: or Move to using forEach instead of a (for of). which is the solution I'm going with.
But Thank you alot for pointing out that My assumption that let would/should resolve it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an Angular problem.

This may help:

```
Promise.all(
  filenames.map(
    f => http.get('data/'+filename+'.json')))
.then(results => results
  .forEach((r, i) => localStorage.setItem(fileNames[i], r)));
```

Comment: Yes you are correct its not 100% Angular Problem,
However The 1st Idea to resolve the issue is angular related,where if I was using JQuery It would have been easy to make the Ajax call sync.

Answer (score 0):

based on @dandavis Comment Simplest way I found to resolve the issue was by using forEach on the list array !

*Modified code :*

```
["action", "course", "program", "staff", "student"].forEach(filename => 
    http.get('data/'+filename+'.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
         staff => localStorage.setItem(filename, JSON.stringify(staff)));
     )
```