# Is it possible to resolve some data before $stateChangeStart is fired?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, acl

I'm trying to build **Role-Permissions system** that I want to initialize on root **state resolve**:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('common', {
    resolve:{
      user: function(AclService, UserService) {
        UserService.getCurrent().then((currentUser) => {
          AclService.initialize(currentUser);
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

and check permissions each time on **$stateChangeStart**:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ($event, toState) => AclService.interceptStateChange($event, toState));
```

but I faced a problem that first **$stateChangeStart** was fired before resolve, so permissions were not initialized yet.

What would you recommend in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in your app's run function. Here is a trimmed down version of how I load auth data up front.

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("myModule", [ //dependencies here...]);

    angular
        .module("myModule")
        .run(run);

    run.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$state", "authService"];

function run($rootScope, $state, authService) {

    authService.fillAuthData(); //front load auth stuff here...

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        var isPublic = (toState.data && toState.data.isPublic && toState.data.isPublic === true);
        var requiredRole = (toState.data && toState.data.requiredRole) ? toState.data.requiredRole : null;
        var authorized = isPublic || authService.isUserInRole(requiredRole);

        if (authService.authentication.isAuth || isPublic) {

            //if the user doesn't have the requisite permission to view the page, redirect them to an unauthorized page
            if (!authorized) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go("unauthorized");
                return;
            }

        } else {

            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go("login");
            return;
        }
    });
}

})();
```

A state definition may look like this:

```
.state("someState", {
    url: "/someState",
    templateUrl: "my/folder/file.html",
    data: {
        pageTitle: "Some Page",
        isPublic: false,
        requiredRole: "Admin"
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting use permissions from server asynchronously, I don't see it in your solution

Comment: That happens inside authService.fillAuthData().

Comment: but how could you be sure that it will be resolved before  such sync check - if (authService.authentication ?

Comment: Inside .fillAuthData I'm using var deferred = $q.defer(); and deferred.resolve(apiResponse) to ensure the promise resolves. Have a [look at $q here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Or have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750814/how-to-make-synchronous-http-request-in-angular-js).

Comment: "deferred.resolve(apiResponse) to ensure the promise resolves." - you resolve it yourself, but it does not mean when you are doing ajax request that you know it. sync ajax like solution looks tooo ugly for me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do some auth logic in state resolves. Better approach is to set listener for $stateChangeStart event in angular.run function:

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', 'principal', '$state', function ($rootScope, principal, $state) {
        var firstOpen = true;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
            if (!principal.isAuthenticated() && firstOpen) {
                firstOpen = false;
                event.preventDefault();
                principal.checkAuthentication().then(function() {
                    $state.go(toState, toParams);
                });
            } else if (principal.isAuthenticated() && toState.name === 'login') {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Do some stuff here, for example, redirect to main page
            }
        });
    }
]);
```