# how to post synchronous http request in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to post synchronous ajax request or how to set async as false in angular [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Example of my service is

```
$http.post("qa.test.net/rest/customtableitem.profile.interests?format=json", JSONobject)
```

My controller is

```
for (var i = 0; i < Insert.length; i++) 
{
   if (Insert[i].ItemID == null) 
   {
      TestInterestService.insertTest(Insert[i]).success(function (data) {
      }).error(function (data) {
      });
    }
   }
```

In this data is getting inserted asynchronously not in order for that reason it is messing the order entered I want to insert in synchronous manner.
Any suggestions

**EDIT**
That did not solved my problem,
I was looking for pointing to the service where we can sent async as false in request headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to $http Synchronous call with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs)

Comment: You can also find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750814/how-to-make-synchronous-http-request-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Lesh pointed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088385/2067976) to  [How to $http Synchronous call with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs) you cannot perform not async call with `$http` service.

However as an alternative you can replace `for loop` to [while](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp) loop, condition is until Insert array not empty, prior starting `while` loop create `flag` variable which would be boolean identifier that ajax success handler finished and next ajax can be sent. See code below with commented changes :

```
var flag = true;
var length = Insert.length;
 while (length){
  if(flag){ 
    var item = Insert[--length];
    // Set flag to false, until success executed
    flag = false;
    TestInterestService.insertTest(item).success(function( path ){
      // We are ready to perform next ajax, set flag to true.
      flag = true;
    }).error: function( path ){
       // Error or not we have to set flag to true to allow further iterating
       flag = true;
     }
  }
}
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: @Sultan does it answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

use **async** Library 
 
link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

**Example**

```
 async.each(Insert, function (insert_record_objec, callback) {

    TestInterestService.insertTest(insert_record_objec).success(function (data) {
        callback();
    }).error(function (data) {
        callback();
    });


}, function (err) {
    // if any of the processing produced an error 

});
```

Answer (score -1):

For simple use cases, you can leverage promises, when one request has successfully resolved, only `.then` send another one

```
MyService.postMe().then(function(response) {
    MyService.postMeToo(response.data);
});
```